# How to implement master and child page like Activity in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to place a common banner and menu on each Activity with footer too.

Can anyone guide me how can I implement master and child page like asp.net  in Android???

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There is a short tutorial of how to make a "Master Page" layout in Android - [here](http://jnastase.alner.net/archive/2011/01/08/ldquomaster-pagesrdquo-in-android.aspx).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could have each of your Activities extend a common base class which has a `onCreateOptionsMenu` method which inflates the menu from the same XML each time.  Though as you can't have multiple inheritance, this may be tricky when you want to have plain activities and list activities, for example.

Another way would be to have a `Util` class where you have a method like `setupMenu(Menu)` which each of your Activities can call if you're doing some more complex menu setup.

In terms of the XML UI layout for each of your Activities, you can include a common banner by using the [`<include/>`](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/02/android-layout-tricks-2-reusing-layouts.html) tag.

Comment: The link in my answer has an example. The Android home screen application includes the entire layout of the workspace_screen.xml multiple times by using the <include> tag.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was pretty easy.

You need to extends "**Activity**" Class,in onCreate function SetContentView to your base xml layout and also need to override setContentView in base Activity Class

For Example:

1.Create "base_layout.xml" with the below code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:background="#000000"
      android:padding="15dp" >
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:background="#000000"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:minHeight="50dp" android:paddingLeft="10dp">
           <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
               android:adjustViewBounds="true" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:scaleType="fitCenter" android:maxHeight="50dp" />
   </LinearLayout>
   <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linBase"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
   </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

2.Create "BaseActivity.java"

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity {
    ImageView image;
    LinearLayout linBase;     
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        super.setContentView(R.layout.base_layout);        
        linBase = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linBase);
    }
    @Override
    public void setContentView(int id) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        inflater.inflate(id, linBase);
    }
}
```

and

```
public class SomeActivity extends BaseActivity {    
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.setContentView(R.layout.some_layout);
       //rest of code
    }
}
```

The only thing I noticed so far was that when requesting a progress bar (requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS)) this needs to be done before calling super.onCreate. I think this is because nothing can be drawn yet before calling this function.

This worked great for me and hopefully you will find this useful in your own coding.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem and solved it using [ActivityGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityGroup.html).
I suppose that menu items will move user to another activity, so with the same menu in every activity closing application with BACK button can be almost impossible (after some time user will have to go back through all activities he had ever seen).

I haven't found any good tutorials in english so have written mine some time ago (it's somewhat too short and in polish only, but Google Tranlslated version should be understandable) check [this](http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=pl&sl=auto&tl=en&u=http://skyman.pl/2009/06/11/activitygroup-i-localactivitymanager/)

You can also check how the [TabHost works](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/java/android/widget/TabHost.java)

Answer (score 0):

ViewStub is the solution

activity_masterpage.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >    
<ViewStub android:id="@+id/stub_content"
               android:inflatedId="@+id/subTree"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

```
stub = (ViewStub) findViewById(R.id.stub_content);
stub.setLayoutResource(R.layout.content_layout);
stub.inflate();
```